# SONAR: config duplicate line for java project

Tags: config, sonarqube, duplication

Maybe it is a stupid question, but I cannot find out where can I config the minimal lines of code for duplication check in SONAR. In project settings there is only a switch to turn on cross project check. Any ideas?

B.R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an open ticket on this: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-91

As a background: Sonar has been using its own duplication detection mechanism since end of 2011 (from Sonar 2.11 IIRC). At that time, a decision was made that the number of lines or the number of tokens should not be configurable, in order to prevent the possibility to fool the engine. However, as the detection mechanism has not reached perfection yet ;-), we will allow to set "sonar.cpd.java.minimumLines" property in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice. That means as long as I add sonar.cpd.java.minimumLines property in the maven pom file, it should be working for java project currently. Right?

Comment: No, this means that it currently does not work for Java but will once SONARJAVA-91 is fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the classification.

Answer (score 0):

this feature is only available for languages other than Java ( http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Duplications )